# LINQ to Xml list wrong query

Tags: c#, xml, linq, list, linq-to-xml

I want to get some data with LINQ out of an xml file, but I don't get it. 
This is the xml file:

```
<Data>
  <Customer>
    <Name>bla1</Name>
      <d1>
        <IP>888.888.888.888</IP>
        <UserLogin>userxy</UserLogin>
        <UserPw>pwxy</UserPw>
      </d1>
      <d2>
        <IP>889.889.889.889</IP>
        <UserLogin>userzp</UserLogin>
        <UserPw>pwzp</UserPw>
      </d2>
  </Customer>
</Data>
```

I want to get e.g. all IPs of a specific Customer into a `List<string>` but the problem for me is to handle the different elements `d1`, `d2`... `dn`. Because the program don't know the exact name when running.
Obviously my try is wrong..

```
XDocument root = XDocument.Load(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + "\\Xml.xml");

List<string> IP = new List<string>();

IP = root.Descendants("Customer").Descendants("Name")
    .Where(x => x.Element("Name").Value == name)
    .Select(x => x.Element("Name").Descendants("IP").ToList<string>();
```

Comment: I think it's an XY problem - you should not store data in parallel collections. Create a class with 3 properties: `IP`, `UserLogin` and `UserPw` and store it in a list of that class instances. Read more about that here: http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2014/06/03/anti-pattern-parallel-collections.aspx

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! But I honestly don't get it, how to resolve it that way. The problem is still the LINQ part. Or do I have to reorganize the xml file then? :confuse:  And what is a "XY" problem?

Comment: XY problem: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Shame on me, I googled for "c# xy problem". Thanks :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to get e.g. all IPs of a specific Customer into a List

I guess you are looking for something like this (Using Linq2Xml and Xpath)

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xmlstring); // XDocument.Load(filename)

string custName = "bla1";

var ips = xDoc.XPathSelectElement("//Customer[Name[text()='" + custName  + "']]")
            .Descendants("IP")
            .Select(x => (string)x)
            .ToList();
```

**EDIT**

Let's make  *@Bobson* happy by using pure Linq

```
var ips = xDoc.Descendants("Customer")
        .FirstOrDefault(c=>c.Elements("Name").Any(e=>(string)e==custName))
        .Descendants("IP")
        .Select(x => (string)x)
        .ToList();
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer. It works how it should. Thank you! Did not know the XPath... stuff. Will look at this tomorrow :)

Comment: @Sylverblade - XPath is ugly, and LINQ-to-SQL is intended to help avoid it, but sometimes it just makes things easier.

Comment: Hey, I am of course open for other suggestions or hints who help me :)

Comment: @Bobson `LINQ-to-SQL`? where is this SQL/Database? If you mean *Linq2Object* or *Linq2Xml*, what do you think the answer is using?

Comment: @EZI - You're right. I typed SQL by habit - I did mean Linq2Xml. It's been a long day.  Thanks for answering my irrational prejudice against XPaths.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that is based on **LINQ Query Syntax**:

```cs
string customerName = "bla1";

XElement dataElem = XElement.Parse(dataXml);

var ipAddresses =
    from customerElem in dataElem.Elements("Customer")
    where (string)customerElem.Element("Name") == customerName
    from ipElem in customerElem.Descendants("IP")
    select (string)ipElem;

foreach (var ipAddress in ipAddresses)
{
    Console.WriteLine("[{0}]", ipAddress);
}
```

See the following for a complete working example preceded by its expected output. (Also see the [live demo](http://rextester.com/TUUO85596).)

**Expected Output:**

```
[888.888.888.888]
[889.889.889.889]
```

**Program:**

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace LinqQuerySyntaxDemo
{
    public class Program
    {
        static public void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string customerName = "bla1";

            XElement dataElem = XElement.Parse(GetXml());

            var ipAddresses =
                from customerElem in dataElem.Elements("Customer")
                where (string)customerElem.Element("Name") == customerName
                from ipElem in customerElem.Descendants("IP")
                select (string)ipElem;

            foreach (var ipAddress in ipAddresses)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("[{0}]", ipAddress);
            }
        }

        static string GetXml()
        {
            return
               @"<Data>
                   <Customer>
                     <Name>bla1</Name>
                       <d1>
                         <IP>888.888.888.888</IP>
                         <UserLogin>userxy</UserLogin>
                         <UserPw>pwxy</UserPw>
                       </d1>
                       <d2>
                         <IP>889.889.889.889</IP>
                         <UserLogin>userzp</UserLogin>
                         <UserPw>pwzp</UserPw>
                       </d2>
                   </Customer>
                 </Data>";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try this it worked for me

```
var xml = XDocument.Load("IPs.xml");
            var Ips = from ip in xml.Descendants("IP")
                      select ip.Value;
```

from the above code

- line 1 will help you load the xml using the XDocument.Load method,
  IPs.xml is the name of the xml file

  - .once u have the xml loaded with the second line of code you will have Ips as the list of string which contains the inner text of the
    element IP in your xml

Comment: Could you expand on your answer with a bit more detail on what you're doing and how it helps solve the problem at hand?